# How to do this with the ternary operator in one line?

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, ternary

Consider this const declaration of int `num`:

```
int main() {
    bool a = true, b = false;
    // ...
    const int num = a ? (b? 2 : 4) : 4;
    std::cout << num;
}
```

What I want is for `const int num` to follow this truth table (which I apologize has been edited from my original question to reflect the pattern in my program):

```
              b
  a      true   false
true      2      4
false     4      2
```

How to modify the above `const int num` declaration to achieve this using the ternary operator?  I know how to declare such `num` to be const using a lambda function and nested if-statements or switch statenents within the lambda function, but I just wanted to know how to do it using the ternary operator.  As a bonus, what if 3 or more such bool values were to be used (with no specific pattern in the truth table)?

Comment: `a ? (b? 2 : 3) : (b ? 4 : 5);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write the declaration like

```
const int num = ( a ^ b ) ? 4 : 2;
```

At least it is more clear than

```
const int num = a ? (b? 2 : 4) : 4;
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << ( false ^ false ? 4 : 2 ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << ( true  ^ false ? 4 : 2 ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << ( false ^ true  ? 4 : 2 ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << ( true  ^ true  ? 4 : 2 ) << std::endl;
}
```

The program output is

```
2
4
4
2
```

Answer (score 6):

```
const int num = a ? (b? 2 : 3) : (b? 4: 5);
```

EDIT:

> As a bonus, what if 3 or more such bool values were to be used?

I wouldn't use such syntax at all. 
I would declare my table as

```
int truthTable[2][2]..[2] = {{..},...{..}}
```

and now simply:
 `int res = truthTable[!true][!false]..[!true]`

`!true` will become `0` , `!false` will become `1`, then, the right value will be pulled from the array.

Comment: Is `b` evaluated once or twice here?  Any way to write `b` just once?

Comment: I don't know, I think the compiler will either not optimize at all , optimize partially or completly optimize away the code. therefore- we can't know.

Comment: Look at the generated assembly to know.

Comment: @ David Haim.  Would you recommend declaring a (static) truthTable 2-d array for the 2-bools case?  At the cost of just a few bytes of memory, we may perhaps optimize better?

Comment: It depends. is size is your problem? speed? lines of code? I think you should specify your real problem in order to get a real answer

Comment: @prestokeys Just to clarify, it appears that gcc is not evaluating `b` twice with the `-O2` and `-O3` switches. It's doing something quite neat, [view it here](http://goo.gl/ew1LIR) if you'd like!

Answer (score 6):

David Haim's answer is great for lots of other values in the truth table.  In this *specific* instance however, there is an easily identifiable mathematical relationship we can make use of:

```
const int num = (a ? 2 : 4) + (b ? 0 : 1);
```

We may not always have such an easily identifiable relationship in the truth table though.

---

The above expression was based on the question's original truth table, which looked like this:

```
              b
  a      true   false
true      2      3
false     4      5
```

---

Given this truth table:

b
      a      true   false
    true      2      4
    false     4      2

There's another way we can return the correct values for this one:

```
const int num (a == b) ? 2 : 4
```

This one isn't really any sort of math.  It's just simply recognizing that when `a` and `b` are the same, we want `2`, but when `a` and `b` are different, we want `4`.  This truth table is exactly the same as the truth table for the `==` operator, we're just returning `2`/`4` instead of `true`/`false`.

Comment: @ nhgrif.  I edited my question to reflect the actual pattern in my program.  So the 2,4 is flipped when b is false.  What's the mathematical relationship we can make use of then to write b just once?

Answer (score 1):

Well in this particular case I would go for:

```
const int num = (a == b) ? 2 : 4;
```

Comment: That's right, my bad.  But it is good to know the solutions to the general case too.